# Computer won't boot with external USB drive plugged in

Tags: usb, boot, external-hard-drive, hard-drive

I have a old computer which is way past its prime time.
It is still running however, so I installed Server 2003 to setup a file server at home.

Problem is, because it's so old, I can't extend the internal hard drives (it simply won't recognize any of my disks). Instead, I have an external USB disk I keep the family photos on.

Now, the disk registers properly when I plug it in after boot, as expected, but when the computer boots, with the disk plugged in, it hangs before POST.
I have tried to find any settings to fix this in bios, but I can't find any.
How can I fix this, and what should I do in case this cannot be fixed? Should I just buy a new computer as a file server?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have found myself with an almost identical problem, the only difference being is that my computers are several years newer than yours, and they hang at the POST screen as the memory information is being printed to the screen.

Comment: I have posted a Q&A for this over here: http://superuser.com/q/1127278/137165

Comment: No. My solution was to get a new computer, so your solution is 5 years too late. But good to know in case I happen to come upon it again.

Comment: Yeah, I know! :-) Sorry I could not be of any help at the time of need. Trust me you will likely to come across this problem again, especially if you service other people's computers. The BIOS system is all over the place, in both very old and not so old computers.

Comment: This post is old now, but what does that say about your computer which was old already back when the question was posted? :-) Just out of curiosity, how old was it?

Comment: Must have been bought in 2002 or 2003.

Comment: OK, so that's 14 years old now. That is very old indeed. The Gigabyte boards I have are from 2008/2009. So they are about 8 years old. But they are 6 years newer than your old PC and they still have these problems. You would think that BIOS would have improved over 6 years? :-) Basically, BIOS has not changed for the past 25 years. They just kept on adding extensions to it and make it even more complex and harder to debug since it's written in assembly. For Gigabyte boards they do it in Germany. I think the same company does it for Asus too, and maybe other brands.

Comment: You would think these boards were programmed in China or Taiwan. :-) While the UEFI firmware may be easier to code and debug, I think BIOS systems were easier to use, and as a user you could learn a thing or two about how the computer works by playing around with BIOS and by troubleshooting these odd problems. I say "were" because most new boards are based on UEFI these days. But there are still systems out there that use the old BIOS, and we have to know how to deal with them. Not all of them can be exchanged for new models as easily, some of them are used by banks for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your BIOS is likely setup to boot from an external device as a priority above your hard drive.  Thus when you plug in the external hard drive, it seeks to it for bootable media, and upon finding none, will fail to boot.  You should try to re-prioritize your boot sequence and set your internal hard drive with your OS on it as your primary boot, or at least place it above booting above external devices.

Comment: How do you change priority of external drives without having them connected? At least on my PCs I have to connect the drive before I can see it in BIOS setup and before I can change its boot priority. But once I connect my external drive it causes the BIOS program to freeze. So I never get to that point where I can move the external drive down in the priority list.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find was to disable the USB storage function. It prevents your PC from booting from USB devices, but it sounds like you don't need that anyway.

If you boot from internal drives then it's not a problem. If you boot from external drive, then you got a problem. If you only want to use the external drive for extra storage space, and your PC is a server anyway, then just boot it up, connect the external drive, and don't shut it off. Or if you do need to shut it off, use hibernation or sleep mode. That way it doesn't have to reboot and hang with the external drive connected to it.